# rearranging words of column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to compare 2 tables of below data

table a

`cust     text`

`1         Director (Corporate Trustee)@Settlor`

`2         Director@Settlor@Shareholder`

Table b

`cust     text`

`1         Settlor@Director (Corporate Trustee)`

`2         Settlor@Director@Shareholder`

i am using except but mismatches are returned, b'ze words in text field are not in sequence.

Any quick solution, please?

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2008, 2008R2 or 2012.  They are all different and may well require a different solution.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of your comparison?  Do you want to know all rows where the same delimited values are present in any order?  Do you want to know which values for each matching `cust` ID is missing? etc

Comment: All the more reasons to have normalized data.....

Comment: @iamdave- its sql server 2012. I want to compare for each matching custid corresponding values in text column.

Comment: @Geeme but you want to do this regardless of the order correct? So cust 1 text in tableA should = cust1 text in tableB, correct?

Comment: @scsimon - Yes, that's correct.

Comment: From which table?  Do you want to know every single text item related to the customer or if every value is table a is also present in table b?  What if there is an additional value in table b that is not in table a?

Comment: Please add the purpose of this task and your desired output to your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443331/how-do-i-sort-string-alphabetically

You are going to have to look at it character by character then. i.e. sort the text alphabetically and compare that to the other table's sorted text. This isn't 100% accurate though since it's only checking that it has the same number of the same characters regardless of actual order.

Comment: @scsimon  I don't think that is necessary as the data appears to be delimited by `@` characters.

Comment: @iamdave granted with the 2 records here, but given that the `@` character would be one of the strangest delimiters ever, I wasn't going to make that assumption

Comment: @scsimon  The question itself is strange...  I think we are far from best practise already.  That said, if you are not recording email addresses or organisation names, it is no less strange than a pipe character which is also very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started you can use a string split function (assuming your values are delimited by the @ in the text) and then comparing the values for each customer.

## The query to compare the values

```
declare @a table(cust int
                ,[text] nvarchar(500)
                );
declare @b table(cust int
                ,[text] nvarchar(500)
                );
insert into @a values
 (1,'Director (Corporate Trustee)@Settlor')
,(2,'Director@Settlor@Shareholder');

insert into @b values
 (1,'Settlor@Director (Corporate Trustee)')
,(2,'Settlor@Director@Shareholder@ExtraText');    -- Note the ExtraText inserted here.

with a    -- Use derived tables to build a working dataset for both source tables.
as
(
    select *
    from @a a
        cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(a.text,'@') aa   -- This is how you use the string split function.
),b
as
(
    select *
    from @b b
        cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(b.text,'@') bb
)
select a.cust as CustA
        ,a.[text] as TextA
        ,a.ItemNumber as ItemNumberA
        ,a.Item as ItemA

        ,b.cust as CustB
        ,b.[text] as TextB
        ,b.ItemNumber as ItemNumberB
        ,b.Item as ItemB
from a
    full join b
        on(a.cust = b.cust
            and a.Item = b.Item
            )
order by 1,2,3;
```

## Query output

Note the ExtraText returns a null for Table A as it isn't present.

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| CustA |                TextA                 | ItemNumberA |            ItemA             | CustB |                 TextB                  | ItemNumberB |            ItemB             |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+
| 1     | Director (Corporate Trustee)@Settlor | 1           | Director (Corporate Trustee) |     1 | Settlor@Director (Corporate Trustee)   |           2 | Director (Corporate Trustee) |
| 1     | Director (Corporate Trustee)@Settlor | 2           | Settlor                      |     1 | Settlor@Director (Corporate Trustee)   |           1 | Settlor                      |
| 2     | Director@Settlor@Shareholder         | 1           | Director                     |     2 | Settlor@Director@Shareholder@ExtraText |           2 | Director                     |
| 2     | Director@Settlor@Shareholder         | 2           | Settlor                      |     2 | Settlor@Director@Shareholder@ExtraText |           1 | Settlor                      |
| 2     | Director@Settlor@Shareholder         | 3           | Shareholder                  |     2 | Settlor@Director@Shareholder@ExtraText |           3 | Shareholder                  |
| NULL  | NULL                                 | NULL        | NULL                         |     2 | Settlor@Director@Shareholder@ExtraText |           4 | ExtraText                    |
+-------+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-------------+------------------------------+
```

## And [Jeff Moden's string splitting function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l

GO
```