# I want to sort each row in SQL, example is given below

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Input table:

```
first           second        ID
vivek           singh         AB:CD
dheeraj         kumar         CD:AB
raj             sharma        AB:DF
neha            singh         DF:AB
shreya          shree         AB
```

Output table:

```
first           second        ID
vivek           singh         AB:CD
dheeraj         kumar         AB:CD
raj             sharma        AB:DF
neha            singh         AB:DF
shreya          shree         AB
```

I want to sort on the values of `ID`, but I want `CD:AB` to be treated as equivalent to `AB:CD` and so forth.

Comment: But you haven't sorted by each row in your example, only ID? Also, please check the following link to see how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please..... use the formating tools. And supply more information. the better the question, the better the answer.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443331/how-do-i-sort-string-alphabetically

Comment: And is it for mysql or sql-server? Both tags are present.

Comment: i want to group by on the basis of ID , but AB:CD and CD:AB should be treat same and so on. 
can you help me to solve this problem ?

thanks @NicholasMorley , but is there any other way to solve my problem.

Comment: @NicholasMorley I made a new answer for the question in your link

Answer (score 0):

IF (and it's a big "if") your id is ALWAYS of the form [two_letters]:[two_letters] or simply [two_letters] then this would work:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    [first] VARCHAR(20),
    [second] VARCHAR(20),
    id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'vivek', 'singh', 'AB:CD';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'dheeraj', 'kumar', 'CD:AB';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'raj', 'sharma', 'AB:DF';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'neha', 'singh', 'DF:AB';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'shreya', 'shree', 'AB';

--Input
SELECT * FROM @table;

--Output
WITH cte AS (
SELECT [first], [second], CASE WHEN id LIKE '%:%' THEN LEFT(id, 2) ELSE id END AS first_id, CASE WHEN id LIKE '%:%' THEN RIGHT(id, 2) END AS last_id FROM @table)
SELECT
    [first],
    [second],
    CASE
        WHEN first_id < last_id OR last_id IS NULL THEN first_id + ISNULL(':' + last_id, '')
        ELSE last_id + ISNULL(':' + first_id, '')
    END AS id
FROM
    cte;
```

Gives the following results:

```
first   second  id
vivek   singh   AB:CD
dheeraj kumar   AB:CD
raj     sharma  AB:DF
neha    singh   AB:DF
shreya  shree   AB
```