# Convert SQL query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to convert the query below to SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (letter, '/'), '/') word 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         LEVEL lvl, SUBSTR ('ABC', LEVEL, 1) letter 
     FROM   
         dual 
     CONNECT BY 
         LEVEL <= LENGTH ('ABC')
    )
WHERE  
    LEVEL = LENGTH ('ABC')
CONNECT BY 
    NOCYCLE lvl != PRIOR lvl;
```

Comment: It would help if you provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe you can try http://www.sqlines.com/online?

Comment: I want a query that return the all combination of 'ABC',
Input : ABC
Output : ACB,ABC,BCA,BAC,CAB,CBA

Comment: Input : ABC
Output : ACB,ABC,BCA,BAC,CAB,CBA

Comment: I try to use sqlines.com/online, but it dosen't work

Comment: Wait, you want to generate string output from a string input?  Not select from a table?   Then why in the world would you want to do this with TSQL?

Comment: After getting the string output, i will use a cursor  for all the output string and do a specific treatment

Comment: Cursors should be avoided whenever possible. This entire question just screams of being an xy problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: i have a solution, but it's not Cool

  select SUBSTRING('ABC',a.n,1) +SUBSTRING('ABC',b.n,1) +SUBSTRING('ABC',c.n,1) 

  from 
  (select TOP 3 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS n,name from sys.databases)  a cross join
  (select TOP 3 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS n,name from sys.databases)  b cross join
  (select TOP 3 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS n,name from sys.databases)  c 
  where c.n<>a.n and c.n<>b.n and a.n<>b.n

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d76e5/68)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443331/how-do-i-sort-string-alphabetically) to sort both sides of the comparison alphabetically, and then compare the two sides with an equals operator.