# Order Concatenated field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field which is a concatenation of single letters. I am trying to order these strings within a view. These values can't be hard coded as there are too many. Is someone able to provide some guidance on the function to use to achieve the desired output below? I am using MSSQL.

Current output

```
CustID | Code
123    | BCA
```

Desired output

```
CustID | Code
123    | ABC
```

I have tried using a UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Alphaorder] (@str VARCHAR(50))
returns VARCHAR(50)
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @len    INT,
              @cnt    INT =1,
              @str1   VARCHAR(50)='',
              @output VARCHAR(50)=''

      SELECT @len = Len(@str)
      WHILE @cnt <= @len
        BEGIN
            SELECT @str1 += Substring(@str, @cnt, 1) + ','

            SET @cnt+=1
        END

      SELECT @str1 = LEFT(@str1, Len(@str1) - 1)

      SELECT @output += Sp_data
      FROM  (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Sp_data
             FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@str1, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) A
      ORDER  BY Sp_data

      RETURN @output
  END
```

This works when calling one field
ie.

```
Select CustID, dbo.alphaorder(Code)
from dbo.source
where custid = 123
```

however when i try to apply this to top(10) i receive the error 
"Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Keeping in mind my source has ~4million records, is this still the best solution?

Unfortunately i am not able to normalize the data into a separate table with records for each Code.

Comment: While it's possible to do this (with, say, a recursive CTE that breaks up the characters one by one then concatenates the result), I think you would be better off normalising your data (say, by having a table that has custid 123 and three separate rows for code a, b and c) then doing what you want with that. If the order of the letters has no meaning and the letters individually mean something, this makes more sense...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort string alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443331/how-do-i-sort-string-alphabetically)

Comment: @ZLK Yeah that appears to be the best case if a CTE or UDF is required. I am assuming there is no built in function for this?

Comment: Vine, the linked answer shows some approaches, but they will be bad performers, due to the `WHILE` loops and the *scalar functions*. Both are known as performance killers... t-clausen.dk's answer avoids this, but will use 30.000 rows in any case. The answer I provide here will be *right to the spot* and fully inlined. It would be nice to compare the performance. I would be happy, if you share your results. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Avoid loops...

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('ABC')
                       ,('JSKEzXO')
                       ,('QKEvYUJMKRC');
```

--the cte will create a list of all your strings separated in single characters.
--You can check the output with a simple `SELECT * FROM SeparatedCharacters` instead of the actual `SELECT`

```sql
WITH SeparatedCharacters AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP(LEN(YourString)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Nmbr)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(YourString,Nmbr,1))B(Chr)
)
SELECT ID,YourString
      ,(
        SELECT Chr As [*]
        FROM SeparatedCharacters sc1
        WHERE sc1.ID=t.ID
        ORDER BY sc1.Chr
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Sorted
FROM @tbl t;
```

The result

```
ID  YourString  Sorted
1   ABC         ABC
2   JSKEzXO     EJKOSXz
3   QKEvYUJMKRC CEJKKMQRUvY
```

### The idea in short

The trick is the first `CROSS APPLY`. This will create a *tally on-the-fly*. You will get a resultset with numbers from 1 to n where n is the length of the current string.

The second apply uses this number to get each character *one-by-one* using `SUBSTRING()`.

The outer `SELECT` calls from the orginal table, which means *one-row-per-ID* and use a *correalted sub-query* to fetch all related characters. They will be sorted and re-concatenated using `FOR XML`. You might add `DISTINCT` in order to avoid repeating characters.

That's it :-)

### Hint: SQL-Server 2017+

With version v2017 [there's the new function `STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This would make the re-concatenation very easy:

```
WITH SeparatedCharacters AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP(LEN(YourString)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Nmbr)
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(YourString,Nmbr,1))B(Chr)
)
SELECT ID,YourString
      ,STRING_AGG(sc.Chr,'') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sc.Chr) AS Sorted
FROM SeparatedCharacters sc
GROUP BY ID,YourString;
```

Comment: Your group by is kind of dirty code, you can increase performance by removing the group by and refer to @tbl instead of SeparatedCharacters (still MUCH faster than my attempt in the identical question)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thx, good catch and true for the pre-2017 versions with the correlated sub-query (corrected my answer). The `STRING_AGG` approach will still need the `GROUP BY`...

Comment: @Vine, No need to hardcode anything here... use your actual table and column instead of `@tbl` and `YourString`.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't rely on a id column to join with itself, performance is almost as fast 
as the answer by @Shnugo:

```
SELECT
  CustID, 
  (
    SELECT
      chr
    FROM
      (SELECT TOP(LEN(Code)) 
         SUBSTRING(Code,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),1)
       FROM sys.messages) A(Chr)
       ORDER by chr
       FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
      ) As CODE
FROM
  source t
```

Comment: It's a nice idea to use `ROW_NUMBER()` directly within `SUBSTRING()` +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table having good amount of rows (~4 Million), I would suggest you to create a persisted calculated field in the table, to store these values. As calculating these values at run time in a view, will lead to performance problems.

If you are not able to normalize, add this as a denormalized column to the existing table.

I think the error you are getting could be due to empty codes.

```
If LEN(@str)  = 0
BEGIN
  SET @output = ''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
... EXISTING CODE BLOCK ...
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to [split string into its characters](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/tsql-character-split-function-in-sql-server.aspx) using referred SQL function.
Then you can concatenate string back, this time ordered alphabetically.

Are you using SQL Server 2017? Because with SQL Server 2017, you can use [SQL String_Agg string aggregation function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) to concatenate characters splitted in an ordered way as follows

```
select 
    t.CustId, string_agg(strval, '') within GROUP (order by strval) 
from CharacterTable t
cross apply dbo.SPLIT(t.code) s
where strval is not null 
group by CustId
order by CustId
```

If you are not working on SQL2017, then you can follow below structure using SQL XML PATH for [concatenation in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-concatenation-function-to-sql-concatenate-strings.aspx)

```
select 
    CustId, 
    STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      '' + strval
    from CharacterTable ct
    cross apply dbo.SPLIT(t.code) s
    where strval is not null 
    and t.CustId = ct.CustId
    order by strval
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
from CharacterTable t
order by CustId
```

Comment: Still the splitter function with extremely bad performance due to *multi-statement-TVF* and `WHILE` loop? There are much better approaches...

Comment: I think using a CLR split function is one of best choices

Comment: This is not a question of *string splitting*, we just need to get each character separated as a derived set. And we often have good reasons to avoid CLR assemblies (maintenance, rights). A CLR-function might be the **best** choice, but I can tell you for sure, that the provided function is a bad choice... The fastest pure T-SQL approach was to use a phsyical numbers table instead of the tally...

Comment: the split function you are referring to needs improvement. Looping is rarely a good solution. It also leaves out numbers. And it returns error with characters like period and comma: try **select * from dbo.split(',.')**. Having a loop for each row will be very slow as @Shnugo mentioned, you should compare performance with his answer. You also have a bunch of unnecessary code in your XML code answer. No need to use stuff or joins