# SQL Compare Characters in two strings

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, compare, character

How could you compare two strings in T-SQL (SQL Server) to determine if they contain the same characters without them being in the same order.

For example:

SAME

```
'671'
'716'
```

SAME

```
'671'
'671'
```

NOT SAME

```
'671'
'731'
```

Comment: What about 112 and 212?

Comment: Another option is to [sort characters in the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443331/how-do-i-sort-string-alphabetically) and compare for equality.

Answer (score 0):

This is really painful.  One method is to explode the characters and do the comparison as tables:

```
with cte1 as (
      select left(v.s, 1) as l, stuff(v.s, 1, 1, '') as rest
      from (values ('671')) v(s)
      union all
      select left(rest, 1) as l, stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest
      from cte1
      where rest <> ''
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select left(v.s, 1) as l, stuff(v.s, 1, 1, '') as rest
      from (values ('716')) v(s)
      union all
      select left(rest, 1) as l, stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest
      from cte2
      where rest <> ''
     )
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'NOT SAME' else 'SAME' end)
from (select l, sum(in1) as in1, sum(in2) as in2
      from ((select l, 1 as in1, 0 as in2 from cte1) union all
            (select l, 0 as in1, 1 as in2 from cte2) 
           ) i
      group by l
     ) l
where in1 <> in2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method works only when you have 3 chars as your sample

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
  V1 VARCHAR(10),
  V2 VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('123', '312'),
('671', '176'),
('123', '341');

SELECT CASE WHEN
       REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(V1, SUBSTRING(V2, 1, 1), ''),
                       SUBSTRING(V2, 2, 1), ''
                       ),
               SUBSTRING(V2, 3, 1), ''
              ) = '' THEN 'SAME' ELSE 'NOT SAME' END Result
FROM @T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------+
|  Result  |
+----------+
| SAME     |
| SAME     |
| NOT SAME |
+----------+
```

Or by creating a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsSame 
(
  @FStr VARCHAR(100), @SStr VARCHAR(100)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT = 1;
    DECLARE @R VARCHAR(8) = 'NOT SAME';
    IF LEN(@FStr) <> LEN(@SStr)
        GOTO NotSame
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    WHILE @I <= LEN(@SStr)
                        BEGIN
                            SET @FStr = (SELECT REPLACE(@FStr, SUBSTRING(@SStr, @I, 1), ''));
                            SET @I = @I + 1;
                        END
                END
    IF @FStr = ''
        SET @R = 'SAME';    
    NotSame:
        RETURN @R;
END
GO
```

Then you can use it as

```
SELECT dbo.IsSame('123', '312');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function with two strings as input parameters. The function decompose strings into table variables and check if count of distinct characters is same and if join between two tables returns same count.

So it treats 761 and 16767 as same strings. If you want that strings be equal by length just remove distinct

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CompareStrings (@str1 VARCHAR(50), @str2 varchar(50))
returns VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @len1    INT,
          @len2    INT,
          @cnt1    INT =1,
          @cnt2    INT =1,
          @char1   VARCHAR(1)='',
          @char2   VARCHAR(1)='',
          @match bit = 0,
          @output VARCHAR(50)='Not same',

          @count1 int,
          @count2 int,
         @count_match int               
          declare @string1 table (alpha varchar(1))
          declare @string2 table (alpha varchar(1))

  SELECT @len1 = Len(@str1)
  WHILE @cnt1 <= @len1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @char1 = Substring(@str1, @cnt1, 1) 
        INSERT INTO @string1(alpha) values (@char1)
        SET @cnt1+=1
    END

SELECT @len2 = Len(@str2)
  WHILE @cnt2 <= @len2
    BEGIN
        SELECT @char2 = Substring(@str2, @cnt2, 1) 
        INSERT INTO @string2(alpha) values (@char2)
        SET @cnt2+=1
    END

    select @count1 = count(distinct alpha) from @string1
    select @count2 = count(distinct alpha) from @string2

    select @count_match = count(distinct t1.alpha) from @string1 t1 inner 
join @string2 t2 on t1.alpha = t2.alpha

    if (@count1 = @count2 AND @count1 = @count_match) 
        set  @match = 1


    if (@match =1)
        set @output = 'Same'


  RETURN @output
END
```